# Django Celery Beats Package Add Custom Model Fields

Tags: celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I am working with the pypi django_celery_beats package in a project (https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/) and I am in a situation where it would be beneficial to add fields to the **PeriodicTask** model, but I am struggling to think of how to extend the model where it will still work as expected since the package will not know to use my newly created **CustomPeriodicTask(PeriodicTask)** model.

So my question is, do I need to store the package locally and edit the source or can I override the fields in the model without having to go through all of that trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the behavior of the core functionality will change based on your field changes, then you'll have to fork the repo and make your own updates.

Comment: Yep, I tried half of the day to just host the package files locally, and got it to work for celery, but PeriodicTasks from beats just didn't work due to missed imports, even though I felt like I tried altering everything...I finallly forked the repo and added the changes I needed, then added the remote resource to my requirements, and it worked as expected after **docker-compose build**

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you could create a model layer alongside the `PeriodicTask` with a [OneToOne Relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) between them.